# How to use both serial port and ble in c#

Tags: c#, uwp, serial-port, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm building a Windows program that captures BLE data and spits it out for a program to read in real-time on a serial port.

I've built the program using UWP (Universal Windows Program) and it is capturing the BLE data just fine, the problem is, I can't get it out to a serial port for analysis by our software.

The easy get seemed to be use virtual comm ports, however, UWP does not support these. I can log the BLE data to a text file then read it, but this is no longer real-time. I can't seem to find a non-UWP BLE program to implement for standard .net framework which would make serial a breeze.

Can anyone suggest a method to essentially convert BLE data to serial without running two programs or using an external null modem cable?

Answer (score 0):

are you using the Devices.SerialCommunication namespace?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication

you have to add device capability.

```
     <DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
     <Device Id="vidpid:xxxx xxxx">
      <Function Type="name:serialPort"/>
     </Device>
     </DeviceCapability>
```

Basically i'm asking what code you have to show what you are doing with the serial port. I have been using the serial port communication on a windows surface.

Comment: Thanks for response. Yeah, I've added that tag to my code. My understanding is however, UWP will not support virtual coms.


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.serialcommunication


"System-internal or on-chassis serial ports may be enumerated by DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(), but cannot be opened by SerialDevice.FromIdAsync() because they currently are not supported. However, serial ports connected over USB, such as on USB-to-Serial cables are supported."

Comment: So you are trying to access the serial port onboard, not through usb correct?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.serialcommunication.serialdevice
I have not been able to find the limitation of not supporting of virtual coms, the link that I just gave might give some more info on the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, that doesn't work as stated in the link I posted previously. As an experiment, try creating some virtual ports (I'm using Eltima Virtual Port to very easily create two ports) and see if you're able to connect to them via your program.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I was misinterpreting. did you happen to find a solution? I was unable to find one.

Comment: Yes, I had to use a work around though. Rather than writing directly to virtual serial from UWP (which is not currently supported), I wrote to a text file. Within the C# solution, I added a non-UWP project which reads from the text file and writes to virtual serial port. The non-UWP helper project is then added to the main UWP project as a trusted "runFullTrust" program.

Comment: @1point8zero61 There is another way to do it other than write to a text file. have a separate program like you do that is a listener and have the main project talk directly to the side program